# Use django-crossdomainxhr-middleware to allow certain urls

Tags: django, cross-domain, middleware

I'm using [django-crossdomainxhr-middleware](https://gist.github.com/barrabinfc/426829) to allow CORS for my site, but I'm interested in only allowing 3 urls of my site.

How could I make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this code did the trick:

```
url1 = '/Custom/url1/'
url2 = '/Custom/url2/'
if request.META['PATH_INFO'] == url1 or request.META['PATH_INFO'] == url2:
  response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']  = '*'
```